# Is there a Stack Exchange site similar to Code Review, but for webpage design?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598) question, as it's not directly a programming question, it's more of a web-design/design related question than programming.

---

> Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews.

The main goal of Code Review, as far as I could understand, is for **programmers** to review code of **other programmers**, and that's a very nice place to be, where you can review if you're using, for example, the correct practices and conventions for good code.

---

Is there a similar site, but for design? Is there a Stack Exchange site that focuses on reviewing, for example, Webpage designs and structures? I believe that's possible, as you have tons of books in the literature that explains the good practices of design, for example.

Comment: see also: [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260) at SE.SE meta

Comment: Maybe https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: [Related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11001/where-can-i-have-my-work-reviewed) on Graphic Design SE.

Comment: @gnat I don't think it's exactly a computer science / programming questions in general, but UX and GD seems pretty like it

Comment: @Kerooker We allow you to post questions about web-layouts at Code Review, but we *specifically* review the HTML/CSS/JS, not the design itself.

Comment: @202_accepted I was looking for something similar to "Well, I did this, expecting it to be a good design for X, Y and Z, is that corret?"

Comment: @Kerooker Yeah, unfortunately your gut was right that Code Review is not appropriate. *However,* as stated [ux.se] may work, I would ask on their Meta first, and see what they say.

Comment: @Glorfindel review questions are off-topic on UX, there is a close reason specifically for it (they sometimes get migrated to GD; where they are on-topic... ish... sometimes)

Comment: @Cai thanks, I deleted my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do accept specific design *critique* questions on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), but a call for a generalized design *review* is not.

Critique/review questions are a bit of an awkward fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A format so we have some guidelines that you need to follow for your question to be on-topic. Essentially you need to include some objective criteria, so questions focused on issues like *"is there enough contrast between X, Y & Z?"* can be acceptable, while something like *"does this look good?"* is almost certainly off-topic.

Have a look through the [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag to see examples and have a read through the guidelines before posting a question:
[What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/52050)

Comment: Interesting. I think it might be something like this that I was searching for. I will accept this answer tomorrow if nothing more accurate comes up.

Comment: Would a question regarding a webpage be on-topic, though? For example, following your example, "Is there a good color transition between the background and the foreground of this (image) page?". I'm seeing mainly logo-wise questions

Comment: @Kerooker sure, web design is on-topic. I’d try and stay away from words like “good” though, which is very subjective.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there isn't, nor is there likely to be unless we greatly expand the collaborative feature-set of our current Q&A-centric model.

Our current format generally dictates that questions have a solution that is at least somewhat rankably answerable as *most correct.* Code Review does a great job of keeping the outlier *discussions* in check with a strict rule-set and a strong dose of judicious moderation, but fundamentally, design reviews are a collaboration, by definition. They generate opinion; they spur debate. And we don't support that well… by design.

It's not that design reviews (and similar subjects) are inherently unfit for a community, but when the very design of Stack Exchange is to expressly ***discourage* the type of collaboration and discussions that, frankly, these topics need… and deserve**, it's an on-going source of surprise and frustration against unsuspecting users, and ultimately does these subjects an inherent disservice.

I don't have any regrets about the sites we have already created. Code Review (and similar "off-brand" sites) was created when the sheer number of programmers wanting to experiment with "other types" of non-Q&A subjects inspired us to give it a shot. We tried a few more [off-brand ideas like it](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc), but **until we develop more collaborative features like true in-line discussion** (perhaps to replace "comments"), this is about as far as we can push this Q&A format.